# NetLogo - selecting agent from agentset

Tags: netlogo

I have a model of male and female animals interacting, with males competing with each other for access to females. When a dispersing male challenges a resident male (i.e., `male-to-challenge`) and loses, I’d like to have the dispersing male ‘remember’ who he lost to. I accomplish this with `set dominant-males (turtle-set dominant-males male-to-challenge)` at the end of the procedure. Then at the beginning of the procedure in the next time step, the dispersing male won't challenge the same `dominant-male` again. I thought that would be easy enough with:

```
      ; identify those males owning nearby females:
      let owner-males-of-nearby-fem turtle-set [males-in-my-territory] of breeding-females with [member? self (owned-nearby-females)] 
      ; identify those males who have not been challenged before:
     let unchallenged-males owner-males-of-nearby-fem with [not member? self dominant-males]
      ; select one of the unchallenged males to challenge:
      let male-to-challenge one-of unchallenged-males
```

However, I often find that the `unchallenged-males` are the same ones that had been challenged before and won (i.e., `dominant-males`), even though those males should not have been selected in the first place. I use print statements to verify this and included a simple error message using the following:

```
      if [self] of unchallenged-males = [self] of dominant-males
      [
       user-message "this is wrong!" 
      ]
```

I thought this would be easy but I've been stumped most of the day on this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing against `dominant-males` of `owner-males-of-nearby-fem` instead of the challenger.  Try changing `dominant-males` to `[dominant-males] of myself`.